# Error building Android kernel: "multiple target patterns"

Tags: android, build, kernel, android-source

I attempted to build a fresh kernel for Nexus 5X following Google's instructions on [this page](https://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html)

- Build system: Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64
- Target system: MTC19T/bullhead (Actually any marshmallow version on 5X)
- Toolchain: android-6.0.1_r25/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/

Exact sequence of commands I executed are:

```
$ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm
$ export ARCH=arm64
$ export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-android-
$ cd msm
$ git checkout -b android-msm-bullhead-3.10-marshmallow-mr1 origin/android-msm-bullhead-3.10-marshmallow-mr1
$ make bullhead_defconfig
$ make
```

I am greeted with following error after last command:

```
Makefile:796: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
```

---

**Investigations:**

Now line 796 in makefile is:

```
vmlinux: scripts/link-vmlinux.sh $(vmlinux-deps) FORCE
```

and other relevant lines are:

```
vmlinux-deps := $(KBUILD_LDS) $(KBUILD_VMLINUX_INIT) $(KBUILD_VMLINUX_MAIN)

export KBUILD_VMLINUX_INIT := $(head-y) $(init-y)
export KBUILD_VMLINUX_MAIN := $(core-y) $(libs-y) $(drivers-y) $(net-y)
export KBUILD_LDS          := arch/$(SRCARCH)/kernel/vmlinux.lds
```

I found that if I remove `$(libs-y)` from `$(KBUILD_VMLINUX_MAIN)` this error disappears, and build continues for some time. I am sure I wil find some or other issue later, so I decided to debug further.

**Disclaimer: Rest of this is a bit gray area for me**

`$(libs-y)` is defined as:

```
libs-y      := lib/
libs-y1     := $(patsubst %/, %/lib.a, $(libs-y))
libs-y2     := $(patsubst %/, %/built-in.o, $(libs-y))
libs-y      := $(libs-y1) $(libs-y2)
```

So I called `scripts/link-vmlinux.sh` with parameters `lib/lib.a lib/built-in.o FORCE` and am greeted with this error:

```
gps@gps-HP-ProBook-4540s:~/andsrc/kernel/msm$ ./scripts/link-vmlinux.sh lib/lib.a lib/built-in.o FORCE
trap: SIGHUP: bad trap
```

Since this output has `:`, this *probably* explains the original make error.

Now, disabling the line containing trap does not help, we get another error:

```
gps@gps-HP-ProBook-4540s:~/andsrc/kernel/msm$ ./scripts/link-vmlinux.sh lib/lib.a lib/built-in.o FORCE
  LD      vmlinux.o
./scripts/link-vmlinux.sh: 44: ./scripts/link-vmlinux.sh: -r: not found
```

I am not very sure what to try next. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind telling me how you fix the $(LD) problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lines 44 and 45 look something like this:

```
${LD} ${LDFLAGS} -r -o ${1} ${KBUILD_VMLINUX_INIT}  \
        --start-group ${KBUILD_VMLINUX_MAIN} --end-group
```

So what's happening is that `$LD` and `$LDFLAGS` are undefined which leaves the command to just be `-r ...`, and `-r` isn't a command on your system, hence the command not found.

Define `$LD` and `$LDFLAGS` then it will run whatever `$LD` is with the `$LDFLAGS` + the remainder of the other command.

If you still have problems, add a comment and I'll look into it further.

Comment: Yes.. I figured $(LD) long back :). Sorry I didn't post it here. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, I was actually having the same problem, your question kinda helped me with finding out the issue.

Comment: can you please tell how you fixed the error, I am having same issue and its my first build

Answer (score 6):

Pretty old question, but I just had the same problem and I want to tell that the issue appears only if you've set `CROSS_COMPILE` incorrectly. No need to comment out `trap`, export explicitly `LD` and `LDFLAGS` or do other hacks.

[Documentation](https://source.android.com/source/building-kernels) is unclear in what `CROSS_COMPILE` means. **CROSS_COMPILE must be the path-prefix of the pre-built tools** i.e. if you did

```
cd /files/src
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6
```

Then, you have to `export CROSS_COMPILE=/files/src/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/arm-eabi-`, so `${CROSS_COMPILE}ld` would mean `/files/src/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/arm-eabi-ld`

As far as I see you were exporting it exactly as documentation shows as `CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-android-`, which I guess is wrong path-prefix.

If you are building on ubuntu, consider installing `gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu`, `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi`  and setting `CROSS_COMPILE` to `/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-`

Answer (score 3):

I'm fixed CROSS_COMPILE variable to the valid path. But same error still there.
Then i add

```
$(info VAR="$(vmlinux-deps)")
```

just before vmlinux call. And the issue become clear:

> /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: No such file or directory Is your PATH set correctly?

I have installed g++ only, not gcc. Installing 'gcc' package solve the problem.
On ubuntu:

> sudo apt-get install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu

Answer (score 2):

I encounter the same problem as you.
The instruction in the document(http://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html) is right but don't tell us we should run the following command to setup cross compile env:

```
cd <aosp source code tree>
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_angler-userdebug  # i want to build kernel for angler(nexus 6p)
```

the upper codes will init building environment for us
the building environment includes cross compile tool under /prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/

then, you run the following commands to build kernel:

```
cd msm # my angler's kernel is under ...kernel/msm
export ARCH=arm64 # angler is arm64
export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-android-  # use arm64 cross compile tool
make angler_defconfig   # run kernel config
make -j16# build kernel with all cpu cores( amd4800H cpu has 16 cores)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the inspiring way of @dmitry-screwer, I figured out the real error is missing
`aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc`. Since toolchains were cloned from `https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9`, it makes no sense that some files would be missing. Then I realized files on git remote might be changed and not suitable to my makefiles. So I fetched `android-5.1.1_r37` tag which was created years ago to get the missing gcc successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Removed `trap` line from `link-vmlinux.sh` and started `make`. Kernel builds and runs successfully.

Running `link-vmlinux.sh` standalone still gives error, but `make` succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of `aarch64-linux-android-4.9`. If there is a  mismatch, such errors may occur:

```
Makefile:796: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
```

```
devicetable-offsets.c: 11:2: error: unexpected token at start of statement. DEVID_FIELD
```

```
arch/arm64/Makefile:57: Detected assembler with broken .inst; disassembly will be unreliable
```

Solution:
See all branch at: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/+refs
and download the branch of your Android version.

for example:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9 --depth=1 -b android-8.1.0_r81
```

Also, `aarch64-linux-android-gcc` was removed for new branch, so you need to download earlier version.